# Formula Error - Pulling seperate column data from initial row match

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2007

Currently trying to make a formula that will automatically match a model number from one column and sheet, find it in another sheet and pull the second number from said row and sheet back into the others price field. So far I can get it to match find the model in the 2nd sheet and even get the price.. but it keeps coming back with an error after the formula inside of the MATCH tag is complete.

[The first sheet with the model number on the left, the price on the right.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F31mu.png)

[The Second sheets layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Nybx.png)

[And last where it says its erroring out at](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TICsz.png)

My Formula

> =INDEX(A:A,MATCH(TRUE,EXACT(A3,New!A:A)*New!C:C,),4,)

As a side note: I'm extremely new to Excel formulas so this might look sloppy and i could be doing it bad. Just trying to make my life easier with these formulas. Any help is appreciated, even if its just leading me in the right direction. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use

```
=INDEX(New!C:C,MATCH(A3,New!A:A,1))
```

Or VLOOKUP:

```
=VLOOKUP(A3,New!A:C,3,FALSE)
```

Comment: This completely fixed it! Thank you for the help I appreciate it.